# How to ask vim where function or command was defined?

Tags: functions

I'd like to know if there is an analogue to `verbose map <key>` (which shows the location that the map was assigned) for functions. For example I have a few Git plugins and I'd like to know what plugin defines the `:GitFiles` function, if Vim knows this info.

The fallback (which'll certainly work) is to search my files for the string.

Answer (score 8):

From [`:h :function-verbose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Afunction-verbose):

```
When 'verbose' is non-zero, listing a function will also display where it was
last defined. Example: >

    :verbose function SetFileTypeSH
    function SetFileTypeSH(name)
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim-7.0/filetype.vim
```

So `:verbose function GitFiles` should do the work.

Comment: or to know where a command was defined: `:verbose :com GitFiles`

Comment: the :com option worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is correct, you can take another approach: install https://github.com/iamcco/coc-vimlsp and use go to definition feature of coc.